# PrintJob printing background colour only

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, printing

Hopefully someone can see something which I've missed out or something, because this is really odd!
Basically I've created a print class which has all the print job code in to print a sprite, however when I print it, the sprite which I've created acts like a mask and the area where the sprite graphic should be is filled with my background colour.

So for example, my 100x100 black sprite looks like this in preview:
http://www.willdonohoe.com/examples/print_job_fail.png

When I scale the image to the width and height of the print width and height, obviously I've got a page full of purple.

Anyway here's my code:

```
public function print():void {

 //bitmap_to_print.smoothing = true;

 var print_page:Sprite = new Sprite();
 var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();
 sp.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1);
 sp.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
 sp.graphics.endFill();
 print_page.addChild(sp);

 var print_job:PrintJob = new PrintJob();
 addChild(print_page);

 if (print_job.start()) {

   trace(">> pj.orientation: " + print_job.orientation);
   trace(">> pj.pageWidth: " + print_job.pageWidth);
          trace(">> pj.pageHeight: " + print_job.pageHeight);
          trace(">> pj.paperWidth: " + print_job.paperWidth);
          trace(">> pj.paperHeight: " + print_job.paperHeight);

   print_page.height = print_job.pageHeight;
   print_page.scaleX = print_page.scaleY;

   print_job.addPage(print_page);
   print_job.send();

   print_job = null;

 } else {

  //User does not have printer or user cancelled print action
 }
 removeChild(print_page);
}
```

If anybody has any idea, or had this problem before then any help will be greatly appriciated. 
Many thanks,
Will

Comment: Just copy / pasted and worked fine, a black square displayed (FP10). Where does the purple come from exactly ? Isn't it just your printer running out of black ink :)

Comment: Hm that's what I was worried about, it was working a few days ago and suddenly after changing a few assets, it's done this. I don't know what's wrong with it! It's not my printer running out of black ink! I'm using the preview window instead of destroying the forests and printing out endless purple squares! The purple is my background colour, the the black square which should be appearing acts like a mask to the background colour, so you can only see purple where the black square is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that this thread isn't answered, and I forgot to say I found a fix. For some reason I needed to add the object I wanted to print directly to the stage, for example stage.addChild(movieclip), oddly it didn't seem to work if I added it in a child on the stage, it has to be added on the stage directly.

The good thing is, if you don't want the movieclip/bitmap/sprite to be shown when you print, if you set the visiblity to false, it will still print for you.

A bit of an odd one, but seemed to work.

Cheers,
Will